# Setting up Utorrent on Linux MINT 18

Tags: linux-mint, utorrent

The question is how to setup and install Utorrent the 64 bit version for UBUNTU 16.4 on LINUX MINT 18 Sarah Cinnamon

I've tried the way from [this page](http://www.howopensource.com/2011/08/install-utorrent-in-ubuntu-fedora/), [this page](http://tecadmin.net/install-utorrent-on-ubuntu-debian-linuxmint/#), as well as [this page](http://tutorialforlinux.com/2015/12/11/how-to-install-utorrent-on-linux-mint-17-3-rosa-lts-32-64bit-easy-guide/), and a few other ways as well.

After the step: 
`utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/ &` from the howopensource page above I get the error:

```
utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/
utserver: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I know i have libssl1.0.0 not 0.9.8 so what do I need to do to run this on the newer libssl?

I've encountered other errors trying each web pages advice, this one seems to be the closet to working. The other errors are to confusing for me to even begin to explain.

Comment: I tried that before posting and still get this error, not about the apt-get libssl0.9.8 what i mean is after i install that libssl and then try that utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/ &   command, this is where i get the error. plus what i read was the newer lib 1.0 is suppose to replace the older version, I also looked in software manager and i have libssl 1.0 but there isnt any libssl 0.9.8 available for downloading

Comment: after trying it again i get this apt-get libssl0.9.8 Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libssl0.9.8 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libssl0.9.8' has no installation candidate

Comment: When i click the install button on that page a pop up comes up saying the pacgake lib0.9.8 is virtual and the only thing i can do is hit close

Comment: Developing the linux version of utorrent has dropped, so choose any other torrent client your distro contains.